# MVC 4 Web API + EntityFramework: Handling external resource dependencies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So I have this situation where lets say I'm making two APIs; Car API and a AutoService API. The Car API manages resources related to car entities. The AutoService API manages resources related to auto service retail entities that provide repair service for cars.

Lets say an application uses both API. It creates an auto service entity for a particular car entity. So it uses the Car API to create/edit a car resource and then passes it to the AutoService API to create a service log for that particular car entity. This means that the service log entity in the AutoService API is referencing an entity that is an external resource to the API.

The question becomes, what is the best practice to handle this dependency? My original idea is to create two properties in the service entity; externalOwner and externalOwnerHost. The externalOwner entity would map to the id of the car entity. The externalOwnerHost would describe the origin of the external owner, lets say `/auto/car`. With this association in place, create a convention for the application client to figure out on its own how to access the external owner entity given the externalOwnerHost. So for this example, the application should be smart enough to know to use `GET /auto/car?fields=` given that it knows the host of the resource. Is this best practice? Do you guys have better ideas?

Comment: When you say _two APIs_ do you mean to separate Web API project or just two different resource endpoint in the same solution. I tried to decide but it wasn't conclusive.

Comment: They are separate Web API projects. The purpose of decoupling them is so that they can be re-used and deployed independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the dependency to be called without an understanding of the dependency, I would save the child URL for calling the entity in a single field (e.g. /auto/car/12?fields=...).

But I wonder how easy this is as the consumer of the API needs to understand how to consume the data returned from the API. In your example,this means AutoService API has to understand how to deal with the Auto API data.

So, my ultimate recommendation depends upon what you are designing for. If this is for display, I would have care auto service know the id and know how to include an auto specific control. If this is for processing, I would pretty much have a CarId and have the AutoService API understand exactly how to get the data and how to consume it in code; not in the database.